# C# Devexpress 'Run Designer' freezes my IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, devexpress

When I suddenly want to open "Run Designer" for gridControl without any problems until now, the IDE freezes and never recovers. Devexpress version is 17.2 . What could be causing the error?

Comment: maybe, you need update the version. https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/T683022/the-standard-contextmenu-freezes-when-it-is-used-with-devexpress-components-in

assuming it is for WPF or Win Form

Comment: How can I access the crack file?

Comment: I dont have idea